# XCode 4 : how to see the entire ScrollView in IB?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, interface-builder

Since I've downloaded the last version of XCode, when I add a ScrollView in IB I can't see the entire view. For example, if I add a 320x700px ScrollView, I only see the 320x480px visible.

What can I do ?

Comment: for iPhone , if scrollview has 320*700 frame then also visible area of iphone is 320*480 and scroll will be visible in iphone area depending on origin of scroll view

Comment: There is no problem with the view scrolling while the application is running. I mean, I want to see the 320x700px in IB like I used to do it with XCode 3.

Comment: @RobinDreux You need to add the scrollview in IB "beside" the window, not within it. Later in the code you must do a `[self.view addSubview:scrollview];`.